# 2 inner joins on same column

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    sunrise.RMA 
INNER JOIN 
    sunrise.S_FLD_DEFAULTDATA AS DD ON sunrise.RMA.ROOTCAUSEENGCAT = DD.ACTUALVALUE 
                                    AND DD.FIELDID = '106014684'
INNER JOIN 
    sunrise.S_FLD_DEFAULTDATA ON sunrise.RMA.PRODUCTFAMILY = DD.ACTUALVALUE 
                              AND DD.FIELDID = '106014687'
WHERE
    sunrise.RMA.servicereqid = 'RMA010323'
```

It only pulls through the first join.

What I am missing here?

Comment: please give Alais name for second join also just like DD

Comment: Please add used DBMS

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM sunrise.RMA 
    INNER JOIN sunrise.S_FLD_DEFAULTDATA AS DD
      ON sunrise.RMA.ROOTCAUSEENGCAT = DD.ACTUALVALUE AND DD.FIELDID = '106014684'
    INNER JOIN sunrise.S_FLD_DEFAULTDATA DDD 
      ON sunrise.RMA.PRODUCTFAMILY = DDD .ACTUALVALUE AND DDD .FIELDID = '106014687'
Where sunrise.RMA.servicereqid = 'RMA010323'
```

Comment: I then end up with

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 299
          The multi-part entifier "sunrise.S_FLD_DEFAULTDATA.FIELDID"  could not be bound.

Comment: please give alias name for Sunrise.RMA also instead of  select * from give column names why because you are joining on same table so it will give errors

Comment: I am still struggling I have done as suggested and am still getting an error

Comment: FROM sunrise.RMA AS SRMA, sunrise.S_FLD_DEFAULTDATA
    INNER JOIN sunrise.S_FLD_DEFAULTDATA AS DD
    ON SRMA.ROOTCAUSEENGCAT = DD.ACTUALVALUE AND DD.FIELDID = '106014684'
    INNER JOIN sunrise.S_FLD_DEFAULTDATA  DDD
    ON SRMA.PRODUCTFAMILY = DDD.ACTUALVALUE AND DDD.FIELDID = '106014687'
Where  SRMA.servicereqid = 'RMA010323'

Comment: Now all of my selected  can be bound?

Comment: The multi-part identifier "sunrise.RMA.DETAILS" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 126